# Hide child li start with Hyphen (-) and show base on parent li in jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

This my html code

```
<ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close">
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option"><label class="dd-option-text">Our Approach</label></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">- Consultation & Customized Search</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">- Dating & Relationship Coaching</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">Testimonials</label>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option">
        <label class="dd-option-text">- Online Dating Support</label>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Output:

```
Our Approach
  - Consultation & Customized Search
  - Dating & Relationship Coaching
Testimonials
  - Online Dating Support
```

But I need out like that(After hover parent li show Hyphen (-) li )

```
   Our Approach
   Testimonials

Hover on  Our Approach want to show
- Consultation & Customized Search
- Dating & Relationship Coaching 
Hover on Testimonials want to show
- Online Dating Suppor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$('.dd-options .dd-option-text').filter(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text())[0] == '-';
}).closest('li').hide().addClass('minus');

$('.dd-options > :not(.minus)').hover(function () {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(.minus)').show();
}, function () {
    $(this).nextUntil(':not(.minus)').hide();
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/7b9ga/)

Comment: Hover on  Our Approach want to show
- Consultation & Customized Search
- Dating & Relationship Coaching 
Hover on Testimonials want to show
- Online Dating Suppor

Answer (score 0):

```
$('li label.dd-option-text').each(function () {
    if ($(this).text().indexOf('-') == 0) {
        $(this).closest('li').hide();
    }
});
```

Refrences

[.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf)

Comment: Thank for reply but i want to show Hide child li start with Hyphen (-) on parent li hover

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [filter](http://api.jquery.com/filter) like,

```
$('li').find("label").filter(function () {
    return (this.textContent || this.innerText).indexOf('-') === 0;
}).closest('li').hide();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8ysAH/)

**Updated**

```
<ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close">
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option"><label class="dd-option-text">Our Approach</label></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="dd-option">
                    <label class="dd-option-text">- Consultation & Customized Search</label>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a class="dd-option">
                    <label class="dd-option-text">- Dating & Relationship Coaching</label>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option"><label class="dd-option-text">Testimonials</label></a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="dd-option">
                    <label class="dd-option-text">- Online Dating Support</label>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Css**

```
ul.dd-options li ul {
    display:none;
}
a.dd-option{
    cursor:pointer;
}
ul.dd-options li a:hover + ul {
    display:block;
}
```

[Demo with css](http://jsfiddle.net/rohankumar1524/8ysAH/1/)

Comment: On hover  Our Approach want to show Consultation & Customized Search
  - Dating & Relationship Coaching and same Testimonials

Comment: For this you can do it using `css only`, you have to change your `html` see my `updated answer`

Answer (score 0):

there are two approaches here.

one is to keep existing structure, and run a jQuery script that will hide those `li` elements:

```
$(function(){
    $('li label.dd-option-text').each(function () {
        if ($(this).text().indexOf('-') == 0) 
            $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

second approach is to change the structure to a proper one for this case.

is suggest nesting a new `<ul>` element within `<li>` that is a sub menu, and **hide them with css**. for example:

```
<ul class="dd-options dd-click-off-close"
    <li>
        <a class="dd-option"><label class="dd-option-text">Our Approach</label></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="dd-option">
                    <label class="dd-option-text">- Consultation & Customized Search</label>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </li>
```

as i said, i prefer the second approach.

hope that helps.